# Set current Date as Default Value DRopdownListFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, viewbag

As the question says, i want to make the default value in my Html.DropdownList to be the Actual Date in format yyyy-mm-dd, but i dont know how to set it :

This is my Controller ViewBag:

```
foreach (var item in db.Pos.Select(l => l.Fecha).Distinct())
        {
           dateday = item.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
           lines = dateday.Split(' ')[0];
           listItem2.Add(lines);
        }
        var fechas = new SelectList(listItem2.ToList());
        ViewBag.Fechas = fechas;
```

And this is my View HtmlDRopdown:

```
     @Html.DropDownList("Fechas", "Todas")
```

How can i set a defaut value based on the actual date?

Comment: You want to set the current date as the selected option in the dropdown ? Is current date part of your collection (result of your expression `db.Pos.Select(l => l.Fecha).Distinct()` ?)

Comment: it is on my collection @Shyju

Comment: So you want to set the current date as selected option and you are sure it exists in your collection ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your LINQ expression `b.Pos.Select(l => l.Fecha).Distinct()` returns a collection of `DateTime`.

```
var list = new List<SelectListItem>();
var today = DateTime.Now;
foreach (var item in db.Pos.Select(l => l.Fecha).Distinct())
{
   var dateday = item.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
   var listItem = new SelectListItem { Value = dateday, Text = dateday };
   listItem.Selected = today.Day == item.Day;
   list.Add(listItem);
}
ViewBag.Fechas = list;
```

And in your view,

```
@Html.DropDownList("Fechas")
```

This will generate a SELECT Element with name "Fechas" with the days(in the format we specified) and todays date will be selected.

If you want your select element to have a different name, you may consider using a different overload such as

```
@Html.DropDownList("MyCustomElementName",ViewBag.Fechas as List<SelectListItem>)
```

I personally prefer to not use ViewBag ! I like to [use a view model and the DropDownListFor helper method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11210727/how-to-put-a-default-value-into-a-dropdownlistfor/11210890#11210890).

Comment: will it has the complete date or only the day?

Comment: whatever format you specified. Why don't you try it and see it yourself ?